# TypeError: string indices must be integers in pdfreader

Tags: python

When running this code

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf

bikeins = open('pdffileproj12.pdf','rb')
read_bikeins = pdf.PdfFileReader(bikeins)
```

I get this error

> read_bikeins = pdf.PdfFileReader(bikeins) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       read_bikeins = pdf.PdfFileReader(bikeins)
>
> File "C:\Users\Naveen
>   Raj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in **init**
>       self.read(stream)
>
> File "C:\Users\Naveen
>   Raj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1805, in read
>       assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
>
> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Find the PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xRWmBH97B23QmWBUcpRbff14CZIOI7Vh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the value of `bikeins`?

Comment: can you share your `pdffileproj.pdf` file

Comment: @Bentaye how to share my Pdf file here. can i send u the pdf file personally

Comment: @NaveenRajB maybe give a dropbox or goggle drive link to the file. Not sure if it is possible to upload a file here.

Comment: @Bentaye https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xRWmBH97B23QmWBUcpRbff14CZIOI7Vh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NaveenRajB I tested and it works well for me using python 2.7. What is your version of Python? And I am on Mac. Not sure if it is relevant

Comment: @Bentaye im using python 3.6 and im on windows. is the same code u tested in python 2.7?

Comment: @NaveenRajB Just tried with Python 3.6.3, it worked too

Comment: @Bentaye y am i getting this error. can u share ur code. or a screenshot pls

Comment: @NaveenRajB I posted my code and the output in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: This is not an answer, I post it as an answer because the original poster asked for it and because it won't fit in a comment, length wise and format wise.**

Here is the code I run. And I can't reproduce the error.

- I run on MacOs
- I am using the provided pdf file.
- The pdf file is in the same folder as the program.
- Tried both Python 2.7.13 and 3.6.3

The file is in the same folder at the `test.py` file.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf

bikeins = open('pdffileproj12.pdf','rb')
read_bikeins = pdf.PdfFileReader(bikeins)

print(str(read_bikeins))
```

Here is the output when I run it, with `Python 2.7.13`

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
$ python test.py 
<PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader object at 0x101618810>
```

and with `Python 3.6.3`

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3
$ python3 test.py 
<PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader object at 0x110588c88>
```

I do not get any error. Can you check your version of Python?